# Does Prolog always reevaluate rules?

Tags: prolog

```
% expensiveComp(+A,-Result)
% otherRule(+Arg1,Arg2+,-Result)
% r(+A,+B,C)
r(A,B,C) :-
  expensiveComp(A,Result),
  otherRule(Result,B,C).
```

If `r` is called multiple times with the same value for `A` will `expensiveComp` necessarily be reevaluated each time `r` is called, or are there circumstances under which Prolog would just bind a cached value to `Result`?

Are some implementations of Prolog better at knowing when they don't need to reevaluate a rule?

Comment: You might have side-effects so you can't assume or prove, in general, that rules can be automatically memoized.

Comment: @coredump So no implementations of Prolog try to determine whether a rule can be safely memorized?

Comment: I just found this, which is relevant for your question  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6970408/predicate-cache

Comment: I am not aware of any Prolog system that has memoization turned on by default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a number of Prolog implementations which feature support for different kinds of memoization, commonly called "tabling" in Prolog-lingo: [b-prolog](/questions/tagged/b-prolog), [yap](/questions/tagged/yap), [xsb](/questions/tagged/xsb).